# Pushing object to array using for-loop in JS creating too many duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

I've created a simple front-end with two text inputs for the user: one for their first name and one for their last name. What I'm trying to accomplish is every time a first and last name is input they get pushed to two arrays (one for the first name and one for the last) and are then combined into an associated object and displayed in the console.

I was trying to follow some of the other examples of this people have on here but in most cases they are using a single array and a second constant element.

My issue is when I run the code below and console.log() the results, rather than new entries being pushed to the end of the object they are being duplicated with each new entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let pairedArray = [];
let firstNameArr = [];
let lastNameArr = [];

function addMe(){
  let firstNameInputElem = document.querySelector('.js-firstName');

  firstNameArr.push(firstNameInputElem.value);
  firstNameInputElem.value = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < firstNameArr.length; i++){
    let nameObject = {};
    nameObject['fname'] = firstNameArr[i];
    nameObject['lname'] = lastNameArr[i];
    pairedArray.push(nameObject);
  }
  console.log(pairedArray);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="js-firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="js-lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
<button class="js-add" onclick="addMe()">Add to Object</button>
```

[image]}

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < firstNameArr.length; i++){` Because each time you get a new name you loop through the name list and push each name again. Just push the new name, no need to do a loop

Comment: Why use 3 different arrays?

Comment: @Barmar, It started as an exercise in trying to create a basic todo list/associated date but the end result wasn't working. So I broke it down into just trying to push elements that may be input separately and then recombined later. It's definitely not the best approach, but I'm open to any advice you might have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time `addMe` is invoked, one new element is pushed to the `firstNameArr` and `lastNameArr` arrays.  But then the code loops over *every* record to push *every* record onto the `pairedArr` array.

You could just push the last record:

```js
let pairedArray = [];
let firstNameArr = [];
let lastNameArr = [];

function addMe(){
  let firstNameInputElem = document.querySelector('.js-firstName');

  firstNameArr.push(firstNameInputElem.value);
  firstNameInputElem.value = '';

  let nameObject = {};
  nameObject['fname'] = firstNameArr[firstNameArr.length - 1];
  nameObject['lname'] = lastNameArr[lastNameArr.length - 1];
  pairedArray.push(nameObject);

  console.log(pairedArray);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="js-firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="js-lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
<button class="js-add" onclick="addMe()">Add to Object</button>
```

Or perhaps reset the target array each time:

```js
let pairedArray = [];
let firstNameArr = [];
let lastNameArr = [];

function addMe(){
  let firstNameInputElem = document.querySelector('.js-firstName');

  firstNameArr.push(firstNameInputElem.value);
  firstNameInputElem.value = '';

  pairedArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < firstNameArr.length; i++){
    let nameObject = {};
    nameObject['fname'] = firstNameArr[i];
    nameObject['lname'] = lastNameArr[i];
    pairedArray.push(nameObject);
  }

  console.log(pairedArray);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="js-firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="js-lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
<button class="js-add" onclick="addMe()">Add to Object</button>
```

Though honestly, taking a step back, you probably shouldn't have all this duplicated data anyway.  Just store everything in the target array:

```js
let pairedArray = [];

function addMe(){
  let firstNameInputElem = document.querySelector('.js-firstName');
  let lastNameInputElem = document.querySelector('.js-lastName');

  let nameObject = {};
  nameObject['fname'] = firstNameInputElem.value;
  nameObject['lname'] = lastNameInputElem.value;
  pairedArray.push(nameObject);

  console.log(pairedArray);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="js-firstName" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="text" class="js-lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
<button class="js-add" onclick="addMe()">Add to Object</button>
```

If elsewhere in the code you need just the separated values from that "combined" array, that data can be derived from that array.